# How to properly refresh a token using JWT + HttpOnly Cookie?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, cookies, jwt

I've successfully setup authentication in my AspNetCore API application using JWT + HttpOnly Cookies, inspired by [this](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core) document and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398276/how-can-i-validate-a-jwt-passed-via-cookies) topic.

Now I'm trying to integrate refresh token feature.
I've found [this](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/05/30/refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-web-api/) tutorial, but it is based on JWT only authentication and I'm stuck at the point where I should add a *Token-Expired* header to the response:

```
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
{
    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
    {
        if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

Because I'm using cookie based authentication, I use ***OnRedirectToLogin*** event instead of ***OnAuthenticationFailed*** event, and the ***context.Exception.GetType()*** method is not available to me.
So I don't know how to figure out that a refresh token is needed.

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE 1**

This is what I actually do:

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
{
   if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
      context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
   else
      context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);

   return Task.FromResult(0);
};
```

Here is where I want to add *Token-Expired* header, but based on what?

Comment: Right.. So essentially you need to somehow not redirect to login, but just return a 401 result with that header?

Comment: I have to return 401 without any particular header when no access token is provided or if it is invalid (I already do this), and 401 with Token-Expired header if access token is expired, to tell the client to do a request for refresh tokens.

Answer (score 2):

Use a middleware that add your cookie to bearer header like this:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var token = context.Request.Cookies["access_token"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            await next();
        });
```